# Adding Google Objective-C API 'GTL' to iPhone project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, api, sdk, google-drive-api

How to I add the Google Drive API to my iPhone project to I can use it?

So far, I have dragged the GTL project into my current app project (so that it is nested under my app project). Then, under my app target's build phases, I added GTL.framework, and then added GTL.framework to my 'Link binary with Libraries' (see attached pic). This throws the following error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Golf-hfbczyaemhyzgvbrtgdxqnlzeuaa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTL/GTL'
```

How to I fix this?

[image]

Comment: After 3.5 years the steps are still confusing and frustrating, can't Google guys just make it little easier and straight forward? :/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I struggled with this error message as well.  This is how I solved it:

Make sure you have added the folder for the service that you are using under GTLSource/Common/ (e.g., add the Drive folder for GoogleDrive).

Under GTL.xcodeproj (that you have already added to your workspace) find the GTLSource folder and drag it to your main project (Golf in your case).  Done!

Now you can remove references to the GTL.xcodeproj that you have added to the workspace.

With this approach, you don't even need to add the libraries (so remove them from the list of linked libraries if you have added them).

The Google API documentation is nothing like Apple's documentation (it's not good).

I should also mention that I'm building an app for iOS and not MacOSX, but this should work for OSX as well.

[image]

Comment: I encountered this problem again and having forgotten that I've solved it before, landed on this page w/o realizing that I have actually posted this solution :)

Comment: For a Swift solution use Rob's answer and see my own http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082606/google-objective-c-api-gtl-with-swift/24114960#24114960

Comment: @RawMean what exactly did you mean by "Make sure you have added the folder for the service that you are using under GTLSource/Common/ (e.g., add the Drive folder for GoogleDrive)." What goes in that Drive folder?

Comment: TNX A LOT, it worked, though it complained that "OSX xibs do not support target device 'ipad'" (I use XCode7.1.1) - I just removed references to Mac folder in GTL Source\Common\OAuth2, leaving only Touch.

Comment: @BorisGafurov If you are using GoogleDrive, the Drive folder should contain the files in the SDK that correspond to GoogleDrive service. Another way of saying that is that you can remove folders for all the google services except the one that you are actually using (to reduce the size of your app).  Regarding removing the references to the Mac folder: yes, that's  what I did as well to get rid of that error.

Answer (score 25):

I struggled with this exact issue for most of the day today, and I found it extremely frustrating. I have finally figured it all out so here is a straightforward step by step guide on how to add the Google API to an iOS7 project using XCode5, using ARC, without having to create Workspaces or any of that.

The answer provided by RawMean works well, but it gave me issues with ARC. I also didn't like the fact that you had to add project, create a workspace and then delete the project. So my solution will deal with both these issues.

1. Check out the code. To do this, you can just run `svn checkout http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ google-api-objectivec-client-read-only` from your terminal. I will refer to this code as *"Google's code"*.
2. Go to your project's Build Phases. Expand "Link Binary With Libraries" and add `Security.framework` and `SystemConfiguration.framework`. These two are required by Google's code.
3. Go to your project's Build Settings. Using the search box there, look for `Other Linker Flags` (make sure "All" is selected to the left of the search box). Add `-ObjC -all_load`.
4. Now search for `User headers search path` and add the full path to Goggle's `/Source` directory. Make sure you select `recursive`.
5. Using Finder, go to Google's `/Source/OAuth2/Touch` directory. Drag and drop `GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.xib` into your project.
6. Go back to Finder and go to Google's `/Source` directory. Drag and drop `GTLCommon_Sources.m` and `GTLCommon_Networking.m` into your project.
7. Now, you need to import the files for the services you want to use. In my case, I need to use Google Drive, so I'll add those. In finder, go to Google's `/Source/Services/Drive/Generated` directory. Drag and drop `GTLDrive.h` and `GTLDrive_Sources.m` into your project. If you want to use other services, go to their directory and import the appropriate .h and .m file.
8. For some reason, Google's code doesn't use ARC, so if you try to build right now, you will get ARC compile errors. So we need to disable ARC **for Google's code only**. To do this, go back to your project's Build Phases, but this time expand "Compile Sources". Make sure that `GTLCommon_Sources.m` and `GTLCommon_Networking.m` are there. Select them, press enter and type in `-fno-objc-arc`. This will disable ARC for both of them. Make sure you don't add this option for any other file (unless you know what you're doing).
9. You are done! Now, whenever you want to use Google's API, just import `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h` and your service header. In my case, since I'm using Google Drive, I will also import `GTLDrive.h`.

I hope that helps and saves some people from pulling all their hair out.

Comment: This works with Swift please see my answer for details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082606/google-objective-c-api-gtl-with-swift/24114960#24114960

Comment: You are an absolutely saviour! Thank you very much. Got this working after 2 hours of struggle following Google's official documentation. Thanks once again.

Comment: Also make sure you go into the "GTLNetworking_Sources" class and change GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.m to GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h

Comment: When all other answers failed, you saved me!

Comment: I followed your steps just because you were very thorough, which is hard to find on stackoverflow. Sorry it did not help me, but +1 for good instructional writing.

Answer (score 1):

Not only doing the above, but go under "[Project Name] Targets->Build Phases> Compile Sources" and click the + button. Then add all the .m files, for some reason most of the aren't automatically.

I also had to delete (the reference) to "GTLDrive_Souces.m" from the Drive folder, but I don't understand why i had to do that part.

Comment: "Not only doing the above?"  I don't understand what you mean.  There is a lot of stuff above your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> **Better to use Pod**
>
> 1. How to install CocoaPods and setup with your Xcode project
>       for reference : [http://blogs.triffort.com/?p=309][1]
> 2. Open the pod file and add
>
>    **pod 'Google-API-Client/Drive', '~> 1.0'**    save pod file and call pod install in terminal. Note:pod file you must give link_with
>      'Your_project_name', 'Your_project_nameTests' after this line only add
>      your library

Comment: how're you importing the files `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h` and `GTLDrive.h` into your project with cocoapods? I'm not able to use any import statement and I'm not finding which module to import.

Comment: @KVISH:Currently what u did ? did  u opened .workspace  or .xcodeproject ?

Comment: This is an old answer, use the official pod. See: https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/issues/103#issuecomment-202017387

Answer (score 1):

this is does not really solve the problem of installing Google API's but in this repo I accessed Google Forms from an iOS app without using Google's API. https://github.com/goktugyil/QorumLogs

So you may skip the installing API part in some projects

Here is the tutorial of how to set it up:
https://github.com/goktugyil/QorumLogs/blob/master/Log%20To%20GoogleDocs.md

Heres the code to do it:

```
private static var googleFormLink: String!
private static var googleFormAppVersionField: String!
private static var googleFormUserInfoField: String!
private static var googleFormMethodInfoField: String!
private static var googleFormErrorTextField: String!

/// Setup Google Form links
static func setupOnlineLogs(#formLink: String, versionField: String, userInfoField: String, methodInfoField: String, textField: String) {
    googleFormLink = formLink
    googleFormAppVersionField = versionField
    googleFormUserInfoField = userInfoField
    googleFormMethodInfoField = methodInfoField
    googleFormErrorTextField = textField
}

private static func sendError(#text: String) {
    var url = NSURL(string: googleFormLink)
    var postData = googleFormAppVersionField + "=" + text
    postData += "&" + googleFormUserInfoField + "=" + "anothertext"                
    postData += "&" + googleFormMethodInfoField + "=" + "anothertext" 
    postData += "&" + googleFormErrorTextField + "=" + "anothertext" 

    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPBody = postData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var connection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: nil, startImmediately: true)
}
```