# Xcode: Dragging external project under project not bringing all files

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to drag another whole xcode project to the navigation pane of my main project but when I do this it does not bring all of the project files with it. This never used to be a problem but seems to be after the latest xcode upgrade (5.02). Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong ?

To get an idea of what I am trying to do see here: [Adding Google Objective-C API 'GTL' to iPhone project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370752/adding-google-objective-c-api-gtl-to-iphone-project)

Comment: Are you dragging the project when it is open?

Comment: I've tried both open and closed