# executeQuery in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

This block of code is giving error in Swift language but it is working in objective C

This is working code of objective C.

```
    [plusService executeQuery:query
            completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                GTLPlusPerson *person,
                                NSError *error) {

    }];
```

And I have changed this to Swift but it is giving me an error

```
plusService.executeQuery(query, completionHandler:  { (ticket: GTLServiceTicket, person: GTLPlusPerson , error: NSError) -> Void in

            println(person)
        })
```

Comment: What error, and what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am just trying to login with google in swift language and this block of code is in swift

Comment: I think this is helps you
[Click Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082606/google-objective-c-api-gtl-with-swift

Comment: Why are there square brackets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**In Objective-c**

```
[plusService executeQuery:query
            completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                GTLPlusPerson *person,
                                NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            //Handle Error
        } else {
//Do it
 }
    }];
```

**For Swift**

```
plusService.executeQuery(query, completionHandler:  { (ticket, person , error) -> Void in
    println(person)
    })
```