# Unable to run Google Calendar API sample code for iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

I tried to run the Google Calendar API sample code for iOS Swift and followed steps 1 to 5 in accordance with the guide https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios?ver=swift

However, I encountered the following errors:

1) Failed to import bridging header
2)  file not found

I followed the steps. I have a bridging header which included #import
statements in it. Is there anything else that I'm missing?

Comment: see [a quick solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046676/file-not-found-in-bridging-header-when-importing-objective-c-frameworks-into-s/34046677#34046677)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following answer from Ryan Heitner helped solve my problem: [Google Objective-C API 'GTL' with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082606/google-objective-c-api-gtl-with-swift?rq=1)

Basically, I should have the following import statements in my bridging header:

```
#import "GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h"
#import  "GTLCalendar.h"
```

instead of:

```
#import "GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h"
#import  "GTLCalendar/GTLCalendar.h"
```